# In R, how can I replace items in a text string with other items?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner to R.

I often switch working directory using setwd(). I'm on Windows where addresses have backslashes like so: C:\Users\myname\Documents, but R uses forward slashes like this:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/myname/Documents"
```

Often when changing directories using setwd() I find myself manually copy-pasting the address of the directory from Windows Explorer, pasting it into the setwd() command and manually changing the backslashes into forward slashes.

Is there a command that I can use that will replace the backslashes in a text string into forward slashes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built in but I too was annoyed by Windows paths:

```
## Frist Install this
library(devtools)
install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv', ref = 'dev')
install_github('slidifyLibraries', 'ramnathv', ref = 'dev')
install_github("reports", "trinker")

## Then use this:
library(reports)
WP()
```

This stands for Windows path and can read from the clipboard and correct the slashes.  It copies the correct version back to the clipboard.  Eventually this version of [reports](https://github.com/trinker/reports) will go to CRAN once slidify goes to CRAN.

Comment: All those commands result in errors. ("no package called devtools", "could not find function...")

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `install.packages("devtools")`

Comment: ok, that seems to work, but when I use WP() I get error "Error: could not find function "WP""

Comment: Thanks Tyler, very elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that if you `scan` the text `"C:\mydir"` it is read in as `"C:\\mydir"`.

You can access what is held in the clipboard by using `file('clipboard')`.

```
# something like the following will work
scan(file('clipboard'), what = 'character')

# and a function that will read and coerce the clipboard
scanclip <- function(){
  scan(file('clipboard'), what = 'character', quiet= TRUE)}
# so you can use
setwd(scanclip())
```

Comment: You can actually elide the explicit `file()` call; `scan("clipboard", "c")` also works. Because of this, `read.table("clipboard")` and friends also read from the clipboard. No idea what you'd do if you had an actual file called `clipboard`....